# cmd for loop variable set issue

Tags: cmd

I have a file named like

**HelfTool.txt**

```
Code1=Value1
Code2=Value2
```

I am trying to get the variable named as Code1 and code 2 in cmd batch file with corresponding values. I have written below code but it gives me error stated below.

```
for /f tokens^=1^,^2^ delims^=^*^=^" %%b in (C:\HelfTool.txt) do if not defined "%%b" set "%%b"=%%c
```

> Environment variable Code1 not defined
>   
>  Environment variable Code2 not defined

I tried to define these variable at the beginning of the batch file but no use. Can anyone help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if not defined` is wrong - the variable name should not be quoted. It should be

```
if not defined %%b
```

Your `set` command is wrong - it creates a variable with quotes in the name. It should be

```
set %%b=%%c
```

or better yet, enclose the entire assignment within one set of quotes:

```
set "%%b=%%c"
```

Your FOR /F options are mostly correct, but I do not understand why you took the difficult route of escaping a bunch of characters instead of simply using quotes. Also, I don't think you want to include `*` as a delimiter. You could have used

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=="
```

or better yet (just in case the value contains an `=`, though it will not preserve a leading `=` in the value)

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=="
```

But I don't see why you are parsing the line at all, or why you think you must test if the variable is defined yet. It seems to me you could simply use:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in (C:\HelfTool.txt) do set "%%A"
```

Comment: I see why the OP is parsing the line: it's for **not** to *redefine* a variable if it exists (defined already)...

Comment: @JosefZ - I understand that will be the end result, but it does not match my understanding of what the OP wants. I read the question to mean the variables should always be set to the values contained within the text file.

Comment: `if not defined %%b (set "%%b=%%c") else (rem don't change %%b)` - it is the way I read the question. In fact,  I'm being in the habit of reading the code rather than a confabulation around (mea culpa). However, your answer is proficient, as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Next *CLI* output could help:

```
==>for /f tokens^=1^,^2^ delims^=^*^=^" %b in (HelfTool.txt) do @echo set "%b=%c"
set "Code1=Value1"
set "Code2=Value2"
```

Another approach:

```
==>for /f "tokens=*" %b in (HelfTool.txt) do @echo set "%b"
set "Code1=Value1"
set "Code2=Value2"
```

Double the `%` (percent sign) to use in a `.bat` batch script, e.g. last command should be

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (HelfTool.txt) do @echo set "%%b"
```